# Typescript argument type from a previous argument value

Tags: typescript

I want the `notify` method in the below class to have type checking on the `payload` argument. I cannot accomplish with what appears to be straight forward code:

```
type UserNotificationTypes = {
  ASSIGNED_TO_USER: {
    assignedUserId: string
  }
  MAIL_MESSAGE_SENT: {
    receiverUserId: string
  }
}

export class UserNotificationService {
  notify: <TypeKey extends keyof UserNotificationTypes>(type: TypeKey, payload: UserNotificationTypes[TypeKey]) => void = (
    type,
    payload,
  ) => {
    if (type === 'ASSIGNED_TO_USER') {
      const a = payload.assignedUserId
    }

    if (type === 'MAIL_MESSAGE_SENT') {
      const b = payload.receiverUserId
    }
  }
}
```

Typescript shows an error `Property 'assignedUserId' does not exist on type '{ assignedUserId: string; } | { receiverUserId: string; }'. Property 'assignedUserId' does not exist on type '{ receiverUserId: string; }'.`

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgOQPbAJYDMMGMCGmqAdgCrgRxQC8UA3gFBRQCiAai8qQPoCCAyvwCSAcWQsAIt1IB5bjH4sASgC56TZlHxw4GAObEIAE3hIhRtXGCIMxPRoC%20GgLK8hAGW7OWg3iJbcilxqjJpQiBC4EBgAbkimiOaW1rb2zE5ODBAAHmCoiMBQuAA22lQJaJg4BETE-EgxeNChUMTo2CBqADzkkADSECBQOcAQxEZUANaDqFiwCCjt1YQYJL2UAHwAFKCQausDIAA0UGD4IMWo%20BbzSJXYeCtrFHAA2geDALoAlDQbUDFUBgjDQoFsNMxdhAjhDTudLtcYcxftR-i1mNgwVCaNRaABydicHgCYRiSTSOQKZR437ozS4EhWLSgs4XK5GAB0ZX0hhMC3MsIcw2KCCgmJ2FBx%20NcHi8Pn4fgCQVINPUYWYDOITPwLPh7I5ESisXi-KMgscDCcQA)

Comment: Instead of generics, try creating all the possible arguments with a mapped type, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9PR7w).

Comment: Was just about to write up [this very similar answer](https://tsplay.dev/w61RDW). But since you were first @caTS, I'll give you the option :)

Comment: I will [also abstain](https://tsplay.dev/mM1vdm).

Comment: Thanks for the examples - I guess now I'm not sure why TS doesn't infer this with my code example in this question 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Potential workarounds?**

Mapped types can map each type to their payload, then we can get all of them as a union by indexing into the mapped type:

```
type NotifyArgs = {
    [Type in keyof UserNotificationTypes]: [type: Type, payload: UserNotificationTypes[Type]];
}[keyof UserNotificationTypes];
```

This will result in:

```
[type: "EVENT_ASSIGNED_TO_USER", payload: {
    assignedUserId: string;
}] | [type: "MAIL_MESSAGE_SENT", payload: {
    receiverUserId: string;
}]
```

So now you can destructure that in the declaration:

```
notify(...[type, payload]: NotifyArgs) {
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WP9aYw)

---

**Why doesn't my code work? (simplified)**

Generics are misleading. It's expected that this should work but it doesn't. Why? Well, what happens if I call it like this:

```
notify<"ASSIGNED_TO_USER" | "MAIL_MESSAGE_SENT">(...);
```

From TypeScript's point of view, that means `payload` can be *either* `{ assignedUserId: string }` or `{ receiverUserId }`, and we all know how accessing a property on a union type goes (hint: not good).

So because TypeScript has foreseen this potential problem, it doesn't let you do this.
Instead, what we can do is write out the possible arguments to the function:

```
notify(...[type, payload]: ["ASSIGNED_TO_USER", { assignedUserId: string }] | ["MAIL_MESSAGE_SENT", { receiverUserId: string }]) {
```

Then TypeScript will know that there is no possible way to call it with "both" types. This gets redundant pretty fast, hence the mapped type to do it for us.